# Problem to show image. Error Bounding Box

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm trying to add some images, but When i compile it, an error is shown, and in the PDF the images are not showed.

Code I have used:

```
\begin{figure}[!h] % h-here, t-top, b-bottom
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figs/Captura1.jpg}
\caption{Figure 1: Screen-shot of a Wireless Follow-me-MP3 Controller}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The libraries:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{llncsdoc}         % the original package lncs
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}  % for images
```

And the error that returns:

[image]

Thanks for all

Comment: Start by fropping the `[dvips]` option for `graphicx`. And then make sure you are using an engione that supports JPG, e.g. `pdflatex`.

Comment: Your solutions worked, if you post it as solution I can accept it.

Thanks!

Comment: also don't use `[h!]` which is likely to take the figure to the end of the document  (latex most likely gives a warning and changes it to !ht` but `!htp` would be better